# Stored procedure not compiling with 'Set'

Tags: stored-procedures, ibm-midrange

I have a Stored procedure which I am not able to compile.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FINGOODSCH(IN STRDATE DATE,           
                                 IN prodln Char(5))                                                  
        LANGUAGE SQL                                        
        RESULT SETS 1                                       
        SET OPTION DBGVIEW =*SOURCE                                                                          
    BEGIN                                                   
     Declare IN_DATE NUMERIC(7,0);
SET IN_DATE = 0;                                                          
/*     SET IN_DATE = (DECIMAL(CHAR(SUBSTR(CHAR(STRDATE),1,4);       */    
/*                   SUBSTR(CHAR(STRDATE),6,2) CONCAT               */    
 /*                  SUBSTR(CHAR(STRDATE),9,2))) - 19000000)  ;     */    

Declare FinGoodSCH Cursor for                                             
  Select TRIM(ORDNO) as OrderNumber,                                      
          ( '20' || SUBSTR(CHAR(ODUDT),2,2) || '-' ||                     
          SUBSTR(CHAR(ODUDT),4,2) || '-' ||                               
           SUBSTR(CHAR(ODUDT),6,2))  as OrderDueDate,                 
          TRIM(FITEM) as ModelNumber,                                 
          TRIM(DPTNO) as ProductionLine                               
   From ORMAST                                                        
   Where                                                              
    DPTNO = prodln                                                    

      OPEN FinGoodSCH ;    

 END
```

THe issue is withthe statement 'SET IN_DATE = 0; (I know I can use Default to set it to 0, but thats not what I am looking for)'. If I remove this statement, it will compile. Compilation error is:
 SQL0104  30       3  Position 33 Token FINGOODSCH was not valid. Valid
                      tokens: GLOBAL.

Also, I tried declaring it with decimal but it did not work

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the declarations in SQL before any executable code....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FINGOODSCH(IN STRDATE DATE,           
                                 IN prodln Char(5))                                                  
        LANGUAGE SQL                                        
        RESULT SETS 1                                       
        SET OPTION DBGVIEW =*SOURCE                                                                          
BEGIN                                                   
   Declare IN_DATE NUMERIC(7,0);

   Declare FinGoodSCH Cursor for                                             
      Select TRIM(ORDNO) as OrderNumber,                                      
          ( '20' || SUBSTR(CHAR(ODUDT),2,2) || '-' ||                     
          SUBSTR(CHAR(ODUDT),4,2) || '-' ||                               
           SUBSTR(CHAR(ODUDT),6,2))  as OrderDueDate,                 
          TRIM(FITEM) as ModelNumber,                                 
          TRIM(DPTNO) as ProductionLine                               
      From ORMAST                                                        
      Where                                                              
        DPTNO = prodln;                                                    

     -- Executable code starts here....
     SET IN_DATE = (DECIMAL(CHAR(SUBSTR(CHAR(STRDATE),1,4);       
                   SUBSTR(CHAR(STRDATE),6,2) CONCAT                   
                  SUBSTR(CHAR(STRDATE),9,2))) - 19000000)  ;         

     OPEN FinGoodSCH ;    

 END
```

Note that if you happened to want to use IN_DATE in your cursor, you'd still do it like the above.  The value of any variables used in the `DECLARE CURSOR` statement are not evaluated until the cursor is opened in DB2.

Comment: It worked..Thanks a Ton Charles.. Saved my day. I am new to SP and was totally stuck in it... Thanks!!!!!